# What are rounds in the context of ciphers?

Tags: block-cipher, terminology

Another recent question on security margin included in its answer the discussion of how many rounds are broken so far. What is the definition of a round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many block ciphers are defined by specifying a round and then running that specification multiple times. For example, in AES, a round consists of the operations `SubBytes, ShiftRows, MixColumns, AddRoundKey`. That is one round and, to get AES, you run that multiple times (plus some setup and some post-processing).

Thus a round is defined by each cipher and typically consists of a number of building blocks that are composed together to create a function that is run multiple times.